# File Upload with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to **ASP.NET MVC** and **AngularJS**, How can I Upload file (Image/PDF/Doc) to server Folder By AngularJS Controller with ASP.NET MVC Controller

Answer (score 3):

you can use the angular-file-upload
first install it:

```
bower install bower install angular-file-upload
```

then add it as dependency in your app.

```
angular.module('your-app-name', ['angularFileUpload']);
```

In your controller, inject the FileUploader service:

```
angular.module('your-app-name').controller('ctrlName',
      ['$scope','FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
       $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
                           url: 'server_url_here'
                   //you can add other configuration here like xsrf headers  
          });
      }]);
```

Then in your html:

```
               Multiple
                <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  /><br/>

                Single
                <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" />
```

You can find a detailed explanation here: 
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload
An example:
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/simple

Comment: Thanks for response, Can you help me with ASP.NET MVC Controller also please

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply...may be i can guide you to a good resource/expert, he has explained very well on integrating angular with asp.net as well as best practices to follow. Check this link: www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/11/the-code-review-aspnet-10-years-on-2.html